# Spring JPA repositories - save() doesn't show child element in database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two JPA entities `Task` and `TaskList`.

The Task class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task")
public class Task implements Serializable {    

    // Id and 3 fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tasklist_id")
    private TaskList parentList;

    // 3 more fields

    // Constructor
    public Task() {}

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

and the TaskList class is this:

```
@Entity(name = "task_list")
public class TaskList implements Serializable {

    // Id and two fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentList")
    private List<Task> tasks;

    // Constructor
    public TaskList() {}
}
```

When I do this:

```
TaskList parent_list = repo.findOne(listId);

Task t = new Task();
// set fields for t

parent_list.getTasks().add(t);
repo.save(parent_list);
```

It doesn't work. I get a `null` value for `Task` `t`.

If I use a repository for `Task` and save the task using its own repository, it works fine.
What I'd like to do is save both `TaskList parent_list` and `Task t` at the same time, using one call to `parent_list`'s `save()` method and the relation in the entity classes.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Can u try adding cascade attribute to oneToMany annotation. Also set the parentlist for the newly created task.

Comment: That works. I have been trying to add `cascade` to the other table, but it wasn't working. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `cascade` attribute to `oneToMany` annotation and setting the `parentlist` for the newly created task should help.